# Changing from a TextBox to a ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a custom stye applied to textboxes in my WPF page, however I have now changed TextBoxes to editable ComboBoxes and need to apply the style to fit the new editable ComboBoxes. This is the current code:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Silver"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                        <Border Name="Border" Padding="1" Background="#FFFFFF" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" >
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEE"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#EEEEEE"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

The above is what I have managed to change, however I am unsure of what else needs to be changed. The editable ComboBox is essentially a textbox with a drop down, so I assumed that it would remain pretty much the same. The `TextBoxBase` seems to be the biggest issue.

Comment: Did you compare the different control templates to identify the quick noticeable discrepancies?

Comment: @ChrisW. - I've identified that the main problem seems to be the TextBoxBase part. I'm not sure what the equivalent is for the ComboBox

Comment: I had to do the same thing not long ago, if nobody answers shortly I'll see if I can't take a min to go dive into a wpf proj real quick to take a look again before I open my big mouth with an answer.

Comment: That would be greatly appreciated @ChrisW.!

Comment: isn't your TargetType="ComboBox" suppose to be TargetType="TextBox"
?

Comment: @eranotzap - I'm using an editable ComboBox. Thus would I not be targeting a combobox?

Comment: o'k didn't understand you before .
so what's not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating a new sample project, the problem seems to be a bug with Windows 8.